# Fade out fixed element.

Tags: jquery, css

If you go [here](http://daneden.me/animate/), you'll see a "Danger Will Robinson" button that is probably set to CSS `position:fixed`. When you scroll down the page it stays at the top of the window/viewport. Notice there's like a white box-shadow (or a fadeOut effect?) surrounding this box. Thus, as you scroll down the page, all of the elements (mostly grey buttons) seem to fade out.

I'm trying to figure out how to grab this cool 'as-you-scroll-down, the-content-at-the-top-of-the-page-seems-to-fadeout' effect. It's a bit over my head.

Comment: Reverse [this demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/).

Comment: Tools like the Chrome Inspector help enormously in learning how to do new things. Right-click on the element you're curious about and select "Inspect Element". Hovering over elements highlights them on the page. You'll easily find the element you have a question about (`<div class='sandbox fixed'>`), and see that it is using a CSS gradient, as Explosion Pills answered below.

Comment: I just saw "Reverse this demo. – Whymarrh " and that will do the trick, thanks guys.

Comment: @Stephen there's a bit more detail below (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [an example demo here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/). Simply changing:

```
#bottom_fade {
    ...
    bottom: 0px;
    background: /* yadda yadda */
}
```

to:

```
#bottom_fade {
    ...
    top: 0px;
    /* as the other answers have explained */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

will achieve the effect you seek.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing but a linear gradient.

Please see it's styles are

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
padding: 24px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
pointer-events: none;
max-width: 668;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done with a gradient that fades to transparent.  The specific rule is:

```
linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

Adjust with vendor prefixes as needed.

Comment: Huh? Just give me a little more detail.. I don't need a whole working fiddle, just a bit more meat.